# Trigonometric Identity question

Tags: trigonometry

> $x=2+\csc(\theta)$
>
> $y=\dfrac14\tan(\theta)$
>
> Eliminate $\theta$.

I tried extensively doing $x^2$ and $y^2$ and tried to equate but cannot manage to do it. This is the right method, however.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x-2 &=& \csc\theta \\
4y &=& \tan\theta \\
1+\cot^2\theta &=& \csc^2 \theta \\
1+ \dfrac1{16y^2} &=& (x-2)^2
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Start from $x-2 = \frac{1}{\sin \theta}$ and multiply both sides with $4 y = \tan \theta$ to  get $$ 4 y (x-2) = \frac{1}{\cos \theta}$$
2. Square both sides.

$$ 16 y^2 (x-2)^2  = \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta} $$

3. Use $\underbrace{1+\tan^2 \theta = \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}}_{\rm trig.\, identity}$ and $\tan\theta = 4 y$ to get

$$ \boxed{ 16 y^2 (x-2)^2 = (4 y)^2+1 } $$

Answer (score 0):

Do it the hard way:

$x = 2 + \csc \theta = 2 + \frac 1 {\sin \theta}$

$x -2 = \frac 1{\sin \theta}$.  (We can conclude that $\sin \theta \ne 0$ and that $x-2 \ge 1$ or $x - 2 \le -1$ and in any event, $x-2 \ne 0$.)

$\sin \theta =\frac 1{x-2}$

$y = \frac 14{\tan \theta} =  \frac 14 \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}=\frac 14 \frac {\sin \theta}{\pm\sqrt {1-\sin^2 \theta}}$ (We can conclude $\sin \theta \ne \pm 1$).

$=\frac 14 \frac 1{(x-2)\sqrt{1 - \frac 1{(x-2)^2}}}  $

$= \frac 14 \frac 1{\pm\sqrt{(x-2)^2 -1}}$

$16y^2 = \frac 1{x^2 -4x +3}$